# How do you redirect https://example.com to https://www.example.com?

Tags: wordpress, security, https, cpanel

I am using Wordpress and with cPanel acting as my backend.

The redirect tool in cPanel provides a way to do this. But when I do it and refresh my website, it goes into a redirect loop saying it "redirects too much" or something to that effect.

**EDIT: More Info**

cPanel has no redirection entries at the moment. Wordpress General -> URL says that the website is on http. However, the browser when visiting the site says that its https.

Comment: What do you have for configuration?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0):

1 Add this to your wp-config.php file

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);
```

2 Check Settings -> General -> Site Adress ( URL ) change it if necessary to http://example.com

3 If it still doesn't work it is a setting in CPanel or your dns

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried General settings -> Site url?

Comment: Hi. wordpress says that the website is actually on http://example.com. But in reality, the address that appears when you visit the site is https://example.com. It goes through all of my knowledge on redirection. cPanel has no redirection entries in it, wordpress says its http, but browser says its https